# Does Angular2 have a built-in concept of ngInit from Angular1?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I've written an angular2 structural directive which is similar to ng-init from angular 1. Essentially it allows aliasing a complex expression on the current context into a single variable on the child context.

Does Angular2 have a built-in way to do this I missed?

I'm not looking for an explanation of how to move the logic into my component, but how to keep the expression in the html without copy/paste at each use.

Without ngInit:

```
<div>
    <span>{{ getSlot(locationX, locationY).name }}</span>
    <span>{{ getSlot(locationX, locationY).product }}</span>
</div>
```

With ngInit:

```
<div *ngInit="let slot be getSlot(locationX, locationY)">
    <span>{{ slot.name }}</span>
    <span>{{ slot.product }}</span>
</div>
```

Custom structural directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[ngInit]'
})
export class ngInit {
    constructor(private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private _templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) { }

    @Input() set ngInitBe(value: any) {
        this._viewContainer.clear();
        this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._templateRef, { $implicit: value });
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `getSlot` come from?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the rest of my code that seemed less relevant. getSlot is a function on my component. locationX & locationY are $implicit variables from 2 outer *ngFor.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I've found so far is this, but it's probably not the intended purpose because it's a bit convoluted.

```
            <template #test>
                <span>{{slot.locationX}}</span>
                <span>{{product.name}}</span>
            </template>

            <template [ngOutletContext]="{ slot: getSlot(locationX, locationY), product: { name: 'a' } }" [ngTemplateOutlet]="test">
            </template>
```